# Get all the rows that have at least one element from array in using Pandas and Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, ubuntu, search

Consider the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

bigArrayOfValues = ['XXX' , 'YYY' , 'ZZZ' ....... ........ .........]

# Find which values from the array are in another CSV
with open('...........csv') as inf, open('out.csv','w') as outf:
    reader = csv.reader(inf)
    writer = csv.writer(outf, delimiter='\t', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for row in reader:        
        for column in row:
            if column in bigArrayOfValues:
                print('Found: {}'.format(row))
                writer.writerow(row)


print('Done...')
```

I'm trying to extract all the rows from a CSV file that have at least one of the values in the array `bigArrayOfValues`  , however it doesn't work (always generates empty CSV without any result).

Any idea what's wrong with the code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it with pandas instead, you can do this:

```
import pandas as pd

bigArrayOfValues = ['XXX' , 'YYY' , 'ZZZ']

df=pd.read_csv('input.csv')

def _check_row(row):
    for x in row:
        if x in bigArrayOfValues:
            return True
    return False

mask=df.apply(_check_row, axis=1)

out_df=df[mask]

out_df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have just to replace the following row :

```
reader = csv.reader(inf)
```

by :

```
reader = csv.reader(inf, delimiter='\t', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
```

Comment: Causes `TypeError: '_csv.writer' object is not iterable
`